# Soap and laravel don't work together

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to connect my client soap to my serve soap without sucess on Laravel. My SO is ubuntu 16.
I've searched on google and here on stackoverflow and I didn't find anything.

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/server.wsdl','SOAP\WsdlController@index');
Route::any('/server','SOAP\ServidorController@server');
Route::get('/client','SOAP\ClientController@client');
```

This is my ClientController:

```
use Zend\Soap\Client;
public function client(){
$client = new Client('http://localhost:8080/server.wsdl',[
'soap_version'=> SOAP_1_1
]);
$array = array(
"num1" => 10,
"num2" => 10
);
print_r($client->sum($array));
}
```

This is my ServidorController:

```
 use Zend\Soap\Server;
 class ServidorController extends Controller
 {
    public $serverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/server";
    public function server()
    {
        $soap = new Server($this->serverUrl . '.wsdl');
        $soap->setClass('App\Http\Controllers\Classes\Hello');
        $soap->handle();
    }
    }
```

This is my WsdlController:

```
use Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover;
class WsdlController extends Controller
{
public $serverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/server";

public function index()
{

    $soapAutoDiscover = new AutoDiscover(new 
    \Zend\Soap\Wsdl\ComplexTypeStrategy\ArrayOfTypeSequence());
    $soapAutoDiscover->setBindingStyle(array('style' => 'document'));
    $soapAutoDiscover->setOperationBodyStyle(array('use' => 
    'literal'));
    $soapAutoDiscover->setClass('App\Http\Controllers\Classes\Hello');
    $soapAutoDiscover->setUri($this->serverUrl);
    $soapAutoDiscover->handle();

   }
}
```

Finally this is my class Hello:

```
class Hello
{
/**
 * @param int $num1
 * @param int $num2
 * @return int
 */
function soma($num1, $num2)
{
    return $num1 + $num2;
}
}
```

My framework shows this error:

> SoapFault
>   Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Classes\Hello::soma(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

But in the function's declaration I putted the 2 arguments. What's happened whith this?

Comment: Obviously you are passing one argument instead of two arguments to the function **soma** with signature `soma(int, int)`. I don't know but this  **1 passed and exactly 2 expected** is self explanatory.

Comment: find where Hello::soma() is actually called, and add the other var

Comment: Sorry guys, I've wrote wrong in my in ClientController, acatually I'm calling the function like this way:            print_r($client->soma($array));

Comment: @Kyslik when I call the function like this way:            print_r($client->soma(10 ,10));
the framework shows me this: "SoapFault
Error cannot find parameter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I take it soma is actually sum, and you translated before posting?

Look here:

`$client->sum($array);`

You pass one argument, an array, whereas your class expects two arguments.

Instead:

`$client->sum($array['num1'], $array['num2']);`

Comment: Thank you man, I've translated the name of the function "soma" to "sum". Acatually in my code, I call the fuction with name "soma".

Comment: I followed your instrutions and I've putted this in my code:            $client->soma($array['num1'], $array['num2']);
and my framework showed: "SoapFault
Error cannot find parameter"

Answer (score 0):

This were my errors: I was running the command on terminal 1 "php artisan serve" and in the terminal 2, I was running "php artisan serve --port:8080" and as you can see bellow, the $client was pointing to 'http://localhost:8080/server.wsdl'.

```
$client = new Client('http://localhost:8080/server.wsdl',[
'soap_version'=> SOAP_1_1
]);
```

I've solved my ask when I installed, start and setting the apache2 server on ubuntu 16. I've pointed the default folder to my laravel aplication and it works fine.